# Executing the code in the Asynchronous way

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming

I work on a small test project to check how Asynchronous Programming actually works in Java.

I tried to display the result on the console but displayed nothing on the console. maybe the main thread will be executed and shut down immediately. Can you give me a better approach to display the message on the console?

### Task5 class

```
class Task5
{
    public String task1()
    {
        return "Hello Benz";
    }
    public String task2(String msg)
    {
        return msg+" How are you?";
    }
    public String task3(String msg)
    {
        return msg+" Not Bad, How are you Jhon?";
    }
}
```

### Task4 class

```
class Task4 implements Runnable
{
    private String msg;

    public Task4(String msg)
    {
         this.msg=msg;
         Thread th1=new Thread(this);
         th1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
          consumer.accept(msg);
    }

    Consumer<String> consumer=new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    };

}
```

### AsyncProgram class

```
public class AsyncProgram2 {

    public void start()
    {

     for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++) {
         CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Task5().task1())
                 .thenApply(name -> new Task5().task2(name))
                 .thenApply(res1 -> new Task5().task3(res1))
                 .thenAccept(res3 -> new Task4(res3));
      }
    }
}
```

**Also good to know:** As I new with all this reactive stuff, could it be some better approach to code following program without blocking?

Comment: It should work
How do You start this ?

Comment: through the main method

Comment: So I copy pasted your code and it works. It displays messages as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @Emiter for your time. but it doesn't work for me. Anyway, I have got the solution by creating a separate thread pool using the `newCachedThreadPool()`  method or `newFixedThreadPool(nThreads)` method.

The code is running in my own thread pool without using default ForkJoinPool and it works properly.

```
public void start()
    {

        ExecutorService myThreadPool= Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

         CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new Task5().task1(),myThreadPool)
                 .thenApplyAsync(name -> new Task5().task2(name),myThreadPool)
                 .thenApplyAsync(res1 -> new Task5().task3(res1),myThreadPool)
                 .thenAcceptAsync(res2->new Task4(res2),myThreadPool);

    }
```